# compare 2 different databases table columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to compare DB tables from 2 different DB's to see where the differences lie, is there a simple tool or script for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[redgate SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)

Answer (score 1):

It also possible with a Visual Studio Team Edition for Database Professionals 2005/2008 or Ultimate 2010. More details you can find on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833273%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare missing rows you can do something like this

```
select id from db1.dbo.table1
where id not in (select id from db2.dbo.table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

AdeptSQL Diff to compare structures of database/tables
http://www.adeptsql.com/

Comment: AdeptSQL was one of the best comparison tools around, but it doesn't exist any more and won't connect to the newest SQL servers.

Answer (score 0):

RedGate Data Compare is the one... Look no further. Once you start using you can't use any other tool. I'm not affiliated with this company, I'm just a fan of their product suite.